# Detect when an android app runs for the first time

Tags: android

I need to detect the Android device ID when an android app runs for the first time. I mention that I don't use shared preferences or files. How to detect the first run of the app?

Comment: Is there anything that prevents you from using SharedPreferences? This is probably a common way of solving your problem.

Comment: there is no other solution for my problem?

Comment: No, Atleast by seeing +6 confirms that

Answer (score 2):

you can use that code block for operations only for first time

in the onCreate:

> ```
>  SharedPreferences prefs =
>  PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
>         if (prefs.getBoolean("first_time", true)) {
>             //do something for first time
>             SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
>             editor.putBoolean("first_time", false);
>             editor.commit();
>         }
> ```

Answer (score -1):

You can use  `Android.app.Application class`  to to store a flag

Initialize the `flag  = false ;`  for the first time.. when the app installs change the flag to true

If you want to store data, global variables that needs to be accessed from everywhere in the application, from multiple Activities, in other words is you want to maintain a global "state" of the whole application the Application object can help.

For this we must make a class which extends the `Android.app.Application` class add our own methods to it, and define this class in the `AndroidManifest.xml` as below

```
 <application
    android:name=".HelloApplication "
    android:icon="@drawable/first_aid"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
...
</application>




public class HelloApplication extends Application {
        private int globalVariable=1;

        public int getGlobalVariable() {
                return globalVariable;
        }

        public void setGlobalVariable(int globalVariable) {
                this.globalVariable = globalVariable;
        }
```

After this in any of the Activities you can read and write the global variable like this:

```
  ((HelloApplication)getApplication()).setGlobalVariable(10);
    int valiable=((HelloApplication)getApplication()).getGlobalVariable();
```

The Application object is not destroyed until there are any undestroyed Activity in the application. Even when the whole application is wiped from memory you can reinitialize the variable in the `onCreate` method if needed.
You can try the same data storing, for example with a simple object with static field and methods, like below, it is a less elegant method, and if the reinitialization is needed after the whole application is killed you must implement the reinitialization in each activity.

Comment: I need to detect when app is runing for first time. I don't need something to save data. I resolved this with shared preferences.

Comment: In your question,  u mentioned like " I mention that I don't use shared preferences or files"

Comment: @Gabrielle you should update your question mentioning you finally decided to use SharedPreferences, or better: answer your own question explaining your decision (and accepting it)